# How to solve vagrant up problem

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, vagrant

I installed VirtualBox and vagrant, trying to make vagrant work and got this error:

```
VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.
```

I ran `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` after and got this following error:

```
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.8r121009

nawalabs@nawalabs-ThinkPad-X240:~/web-dev/lighthouse$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-13-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-13-generic

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run


/sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

What can I do?

After installing linux headers-generic and doing `sudo vboxconfig`, i got this error message showing up:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-13-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-13-generic
There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

Comment: Did you enable virtualization support in your system's BIOS?

Comment: Try installing the requested kernel headers using `sudo apt install  linux-headers-generic` and then run `sudo vboxconfig` again.

Comment: This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel for adding new hardware support to the system.